# Not getting the same output in different IDE(s)

Tags: c++, c++14

I am using the same code and same inputs in my program but getting different outputs in different IDE(s).

Question: https://www.codechef.com/FLMOCK01/problems/LAPIN

My solution:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int testCase=0;
    cin>>testCase;
    while(testCase>0){

        int i=0,m=0;
        string str;
        cin.clear();
        cin.sync();
        getline(cin, str);
        string str1;
        string str2;
        if((str.size()%2)==0){
            m=str.size()/2;
            str1.resize(m);
            str2.resize(m);
            for(i=0;i<m;i++){
                str1[i] = str[i];
            }
            for(i=m;i<str.size();i++){
                str2[i-m] = str[i];
            }
        }
        else{
            m=floor(str.size()/2);
            str1.resize(m);
            str2.resize(m);
            for(i=0;i<m;i++){
                str1[i] = str[i];
            }
            for(i=m+1;i<str.size();i++){
                str2[i-m-1] = str[i];
            }
        }
        sort(str1.begin(), str1.end());
        sort(str2.begin(), str2.end());
        if(str1==str2){
            cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"NO"<<endl;
        }

        testCase--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output in VS Code and code::blocks :YES
NO
YES
YES
NO
NO

[image]

Output in CodeChef IDE, xCode, ideone:
YES
YES
NO
YES
YES
NO
[image]

Comment: You know you could just copy/paste your console output rather than providing a screenshot?

Comment: Added before respective ss

Comment: IDEs are just a bit more than fancy text editors. What counts is the compiler you are using (and possibly different flags you are passing)

Comment: Most likely, the reason for such an issue is undefined behavior somewhere in your code.

Comment: replace all your `[]` with `at` is probably a good start - or read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The output differs because str can be empty.  Add `if (str.empty()) continue;` after the getline to skip empty strings.  Also can get rid of a lot of code by doing `auto m = str.size();`, `auto str1 = str.substr(0, m / 2);` and `auto str2 = str.substr(m - m / 2);`

Answer (score 0):

Your program appears to (correctly) check whether the first half and second half of the string contain the same set of characters (ignoring the middle one). In this sense, the first bunch of outputs (YES NO YES YES NO NO) appear to be correct.

If you add outputs of the strings the program ends up with, you can see what is going wrong: https://ideone.com/ap422m

```
if(str1==str2)
    cout<<"YES " << str1 << "|" << str2 <<endl;
else
    cout<<"NO " << str1 << "|" << str2 <<endl;
```

Output:

```
YES |
YES ag|ag
NO ab|de
YES or|or
YES xy|xy
NO abb|aab
```

So it does the correct checks, but it reads the initial line ending as the first input. I would just use `getline(cin, str);` at the start like you do it later to prevent this from happening.